# "ata2: link is slow to respond, please be patient" during boot

Tags: hard-drive, boot-failure

I have a KINGSTON SV100S264G solid-state drive in my Lenovo ThinkPad. Ubuntu 12.04 was booting just fine until a few days ago, it started to boot **very** slowly.  More like it did not want to boot up normally but in recovery mode or with a LiveCD.

Error:

> ata2: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)

This happens to me three times, then it says:

> ata2: link is set to 1.5 Gbps (or something like that)

I do not know what caused this or how to fix it.  Also this problem is not allowing me to install Ubuntu 12.10 or 12.04.

My question is, this is a bug that can be fixed or is my drive physically broken?

Update: It seems that I can install Windows 7 just fine but Ubuntu will give me this error.  It means that it has to be a bug then.  But what is it?

Update 2: I have brought new solid state hard drive and new memory (I did a mem test and it keeps on failing test #7) and I'm still hitting this error.  Also I'm getting the softlink restart error (or something like that) along with this error.

Update 3: I think I need to update the BIOS.

Comment: Can you delete this one, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my broke DVD/CD drive caused that error.