# Slow Ubuntu Boot [ata2: SRST failed (errno=-16)] and [ata2: reset failed, giving up]

Tags: boot, hard-drive, sata

[This Motherboard](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/P67AGD65_B3.html) with a triple boot setup, booting in AHCI mode

Here is the relevant message (pulled from `dmesg`), note the long delay in timestamp between them:

```
[    6.528119] ata2: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=-19)
[   11.028120] ata2: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[   16.540117] ata2: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=-19)
[   21.040117] ata2: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[   26.552117] ata2: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=-19)
[   56.072118] ata2: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[   56.072125] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[   61.104117] ata2: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[   61.104142] ata2: reset failed, giving up
```

Seems to work fine on Windows. It's just an Ubuntu issue.

All my drives seem firmly connected, with no jumpers, most are SSD but some are IDE. I have like 6 drives. One is a Hackintosh (Mac GPT drive) and another is Windows. One SSD is connected via eSATA

I don't know if `ata2` is the same as `/dev/sdb` but if it is, this may be interesting:

```
$ sudo fsck /dev/sdb                                                                                         
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a gpt partition table in /dev/sdb
```

A commentary on the cause: https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2006-October/msg03892.html

Because it's a GPT hackintosh drive:

```
$ sudo gdisk /dev/sdb -l
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sdb: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Model: ST31000524AS    
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 384E6D96-A1EE-4D32-8FE5-14B63E4BF049
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 262157 sectors (128.0 MiB)
```

Verify disk passes:

```
$ sudo gdisk /dev/sdb
$ v
No problems found. 262157 free sectors (128.0 MiB) available in 2
segments, the largest of which is 262151 (128.0 MiB) in size.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Step 1 - Identify ATA2

It's a guess that `ATA2` references `/dev/sdb`. The way to find out for sure is using:

```
$ ll /sys/block/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Apr 10 16:46 ./
dr-xr-xr-x 13 root root 0 Apr  4 21:05 ../
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Apr 10 16:46 loop0 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop0/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Apr 10 16:46 loop1 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop1/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Apr 10 16:46 loop2 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop2/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Apr 10 16:46 loop3 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop3/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Apr 10 16:46 loop4 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop4/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Apr 10 16:46 loop5 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop5/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Apr 10 16:46 loop6 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop6/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Apr 10 16:46 loop7 -> ../devices/virtual/block/loop7/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Apr 10 16:46 nvme0n1 -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:3e:00.0/nvme/nvme0/nvme0n1/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Apr 10 16:46 sda -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:17.0/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sda/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Apr 10 16:46 sr0 -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sr0/
```

Ignore the `loop1` through `loop7` entries.

- `sda` (a hard drive) is on channel `ata2`
- `nvme0n1` (an SSD) is on `0000:3e:00.0` (actually hardwired to the CPU @ 40 GB/s)
- `sr0` is on `usb1`

So your first step is to discover which devices are on `ata2`

## Step 2 - Check devices

`ide` devices can be chained with master/slave arrangement and if on `ata2` you might need to check their settings whilst removing them one by one to ascertain which is defective.

Someone with same error discovered their DVD/CD drive on `ata2` was the culprit and defective: ["ata2: link is slow to respond, please be patient" during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203655/ata2-link-is-slow-to-respond-please-be-patient-during-boot)

Another person found a defective SSD was the problem: [ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?312834-ata1-link-is-slow-to-respond-please-be-patient-(ready-0))

By all means run `fsck` or whatever drive testing utilities at your disposal too.

Comment: I'm traveling so I can't verify this yet but I'll give you the bounty and i'll followup later